# Word for the person you want to be?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the person you aspire to be?

Comment: I think that word is "Batman".

Comment: Batman in the making...

Answer (score 1):

> **Role Model**
>
> a person who someone admires and whose behaviour they try to copy.

Source: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/role-model)